# Cytoscape JS: Catching graphs 'boxend' event

Tags: graph, dojo, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I have a cytoscape graph added to my web app. In the core's configuration I've set the **boxSelectionEnabled** to true. 
This is letting me draw a Box with holding Shift or Ctrl around graph elements.

Now i am trying to read all these elements upon the **[boxend](http://js.cytoscape.org/#collection/events)** event of graph like this,

```
this.cy.on("boxend", lang.hitch(this, function (event) {
     console.log("boxend");
     //read selected elements of graph by boxselection
}));
```

But, this even is not triggering. I tried with other box events such as **boxstart,boxselect,box** but those are not working as well. Although, I tried same with events such as **tap,cxttap** events and they are working fine without any issue.

So, is there any way to get all the box selection elements from graph with these events.

Thanks,
Suraj.

Answer (score 0):

`cy.on('boxend')` seems to be working fine.  You probably have an issue with wrapping the callback the way you have.